# Fixing broken USB drivers when upgrading from Windows 10 LTSB 2015 to LTSB 2016

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, windows-update, recovery

I recently upgraded my computer from Windows 10 LTSB 2015 to Windows 10 LTSB 2016. I forgot, however, that Windows 10 1607 (LTSB 2016) uses USB drivers which are not compatible with my computer, which is not an issue in RTM (LTSB 2015) or versions after 1607. Because of this, I can no longer use any USB input devices. I tried booting from a recovery disk to roll back the update and install the proper USB drivers before upgrading again, but I have no system restore points and the "Uninstall Updates" feature does not work. Please help me with this problem. (Note: I just need a way to install USB drivers so I can use my input devices in LTSB 2016; rolling back the OS version is not strictly necessary unless that is the only possible solution)

UPDATE: I tried reinstalling LTSB 2015 then manually installing my motherboard (chipset + ASMedia USB) drivers, but they mysteriously stopped working once I upgraded to LTSB 2016. It's almost like the upgrade is replacing my perfectly good USB drivers with broken ones.

Comment: @John - LTSB versions are supported for 10 years.

Comment: @AcinonX - If there is no option to rollback to the previous version your only option is a clean install to the version you want to use (since it’s impossible to perform an in-place install to a build lower than you have installed).

Comment: @Ramhound, Yes I looked up. LTSB 2016 is (apparently) the last LTSB version of Windows 10, so it will (apparently) go a year beyond mainstream WIndows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound okay, my install is relatively new, so I can just reinstall LTSB 2015 without much issue, add the proper USB and chipset drivers, then upgrade to LTSB 2016 again.